# Recording a screencast with a webcam

Tags: quicktime, webcam, macos

Quicktime can be used to record screen casts, which captures a video of the events in the screen - with or without the audio from the microphone.

Many screencasts also capture the webcam in the lower-right part of the screen.

**How can quicktime include the video from the webcam in its screencasts?**

Answer (score 13):

1. Start by selecting "New Video Recording" from the File menu.
2. Quicktime Player will open a preview window streaming your webcam video.  Resize and position as desired.
3. Select "Float on Top" from the View menu.
4. Now start your screen recording.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was amazed that this worked as intended. Didn't realise you could have both a movie and screen recording session at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You can start two separate recordings, especially if you have an external screen like I do.

In Quicktime, first you start a normal video recording using the web cam (in my case the built-in cam), move the window to the secondary screen, then start a screen recording on the main screen, not showing the webcam video window.

So you get two separate recordings and you can edit them together afterwards, enlarging or minimizing the webcam video as needed.

Not sure if both videos would record sound from the same mic. I didn't test. In my case the webcam recorded the internal mic, and the screen video recorded the mic plugged into a HQ USB sound card.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible with Quicktime but there is free app which allow you to add webcam in desktop recordings - https://www.monosnap.com/